# Storing referrer URL in cookie

Tags: javascript, url, cookies, delimiter, referrer

I want to store several name value pairs in a single cookie on the client. One of those name value pairs is the document referrer. I am not sure what characters I can expect to find in the referrer, so I am not sure what delimiter to choose.

Let's say I choose the tilde ~ character to delimit the name from the value, and the pipe | character to delimit the name value pairs. Then I might end up with a cookie like this:

```
my_cookie=a~1|b~2|c~3
```

Now let's say my referrer is http://www.google.com/search?q=the~middle, then my cookie would now be:

```
my_cookie=a~1|b~2|c~3|referrer~http://www.google.com/search?q=the~middle
```

I don't think I can rely on the tilde character being encoded as %7E in the referrer URL (or can I?) and therefore I would not be able to parse my cookie to get the component parts out.

So my questions are:
(1) Is there a safe choice of character for my two delimiters?
(2) Could I rely on ~ and | always being encoded in the referrer?

Many Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to "rely on the tilde character being encoded as %7E" but you can certainly store it that way in the cookie by replacing all ~ with %7E

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Cookies cant have spaces, so my answer is invalid. thanks user649650.

You could use the ~ character in a way that might never be stored in a URL. A space will always be encoded as %20 you could use "~ " as the delimeter

```
my_cookie=a~ 1|b~ 2|c~ 3|referrer~ http://www.google.com/search?q=the~middle
```

would handle this case

```
my_cookie=a~ 1|b~ 2|c~ 3|referrer~ http://www.google.com/search?q=the~%20middle
```

Comment: Spaces are not legal in a cookie value.